# How do I get the id of an object that created a point in a path?

Tags: path-finding, game-maker, path, game-maker-studio-2

I'm making a rollercoaster tycoon type game. As the title says, I need to get the id of an object that created a path point. These points are currently greated by the rail pieces. I need this because each rail type (down, up, corners, etc) decides how fast the cart is going to go. The cart follows a path, with points created when a new rail is created. Normally, I would just use instance_place, but since the coaster has multiple levels (defined by z), I can't use this because some rails will overlap other. If you have any suggestions, I will be very grateful! For more information just ask and I will respond. Thank you for your time.

Here's a screenshot of the game for reference (the blue thing is the cart, the white numbers are the added or subtracted speed for that particular rail type):

[image]

Comment: If you make an array of rail piece ids that corresponds to the path points when building the track, you can consult it later.

Comment: @Foxwarrior Great suggestion, but when I want to retrieve the position of the cart on the path I have to use path_position. The problem is that path_position gives a percentage between 0 and 1 of 100 divided by the path length. Since this number only can have 2 decimals, a path can never be longer that 100 points. Any thoughts on how to increase this number?

Comment: Well, you could... make a new path every 100 points? Or maybe independently track the path position yourself, add some amount every frame that matches the current path speed. That'd be annoyingly prone to errors and desynchronization though...

Comment: @Foxwarrior Not bad ideas, first one might actually work, but I feel like it would give me more problems than solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure the Path system is that great for your purposes actually, you might want to work out your own way of moving the cart along the track instead.